# How to deal with violent stray dog

Tags: dogs, strays

I love dogs and all other animals, and have a 4 year old Lab. The place where I live, there are 5 stray dogs. I love all of them and feed them everyday thrice when I take my kid out.

One of them is really, really bad. He bites, and even urinates on the other 4 dogs who are unable to retaliate when he attacks. He does that without a reason, he just doesn't like any of them, probably out of a fear that they eat food that would otherwise be given just to him.

Whenever he sees any other dog out in the sun, he attacks him/her mercilessly. I've feeding that attacker dog from very beginning, ignoring his activities as childish, but in recent months he has become much more vicious. He is biting the other dogs really hard, sometimes on the leg, crotch, or ears, and urinating on them.

I am so damn angry seeing all this and willing to kill him, but something is stopping me, perhaps my love towards them. What should I do so all this stops and those other 4 dogs can live without fear? (Obviously, I can't really take all 4 into my house.)

Comment: Might be unrealistic but are you able to separate him from the rest? Either by yourself or the help of someone like a dog catcher / humane society, or even if it had to result to the police? Perhaps the correct answer is to put it down but relocating seems the more "humane" way

Comment: @EricF That's indeed a good suggestion! I'll see if i can lure him to get into my car and drop somewhere far away (that's not easy though) :) There have been many 'unsuccessful' attempts to catch that one by other people/dog catcher in past, he is so *** clever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a strong possability that the "mean" dog has begun to view you and your home as "his". If so, then his behavior may be his way of protecting his territory.
As sweet and noble as that might be, he's physically hurting other dogs. And that makes him dangerous. If he's attacking other animals as viciously as you indicate, there's no way to tell if he'd attack a neighborhood kid, or you. You might think you are safe (yourself) because you are the one feeding him, but there is still a chance that the dog might lunge for the food you are trying to give to another stray.
Do not put this dog in your car. (First of all, I cannot picture you dumping this dog in the middle of nowhere. Second of all, this dog doesn't deserve that.) Do not handle this alone. Call your local Animal Countrol office, or a local Dog Rescue, or a Veterinarians' office. Let them deal with this. Be somewhere else when they come and let them know a) there are 5 strays - not just one, and b) one of those strays is dangerous.
Don't feel bad about this. Those dogs need to be in a better environment and you cannot expect yourself to give that to them. The best thing you can do is to try to get them the help they need. There's no shame in that. You can only do what you can do.